# Cannot access server on Virtual Box from the host?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 in Virtual Box on MacOS. I setup a `localhost` server in Ubuntu using Python Flask running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` I am trying to access this localhost from my Mac, but can’t. I used Bridge type connection for the virtual box so that my mac and the virtual box both could have IP address. Here is a picture of my virtual box network settings:

[image: Virtual Box Network settings]

Ubuntu address is `192.168.1.169`. When I type `192.168.1.169:5000` I can't get anything, it never ends loading. I also tried opening Ubuntu firewall to port `5000`. No luck. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Python Flask, but that said if you are running the server off of `127.0.0.1` you are simply restricting it to the `localhost` and nothing else. This is not a Python Flask specific concept but a general networking concept.

For most any application running on a server, to get that application to be available on the network on any setup, you need to run the application on the IP address of `0.0.0.0`. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027113/117259) on this other answer found on Stack Overflow. And [as explained clearly in the official Python Flask Quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/):

> **Externally Visible Server**
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by adding --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> ```
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
> ```
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

If you don’t want an application to be available on all interfaces, you would need to assign your machine a static IP address and then set that `flask run --host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to use that specific static IP address. But for something like this—where you are running it on a router via DHCP for personal development use, binding to `0.0.0.0` is not a big concern.